# Cannot get the previous session when new session is assigned using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am trying to store the sessions using PHP. But when i am trying to store new session value,after storing it I could not get the previous session value. Here is my code:

```
id=17;
var url="common.php?action=savecid";
$.post(url,{"cat_data":id},function(data){  
var obj=JSON.parse(data);
console.log('catdata',obj);
})
```

Here I am trying to store the cat_data into session and the php code is given below.

```
if($action=='savecid'){
    $id=$_POST['cat_data'];
    session_start();
    //if(isset($_SESSION['cid']) && !empty($_SESSION['cid'])){
    if(array_key_exists('cid',$_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION['cid'])) {
        //unset($_SESSION['cid']);
        session_unset('cid');
        $_SESSION['cid']=$id;
        $flag="true";

    }else{
        $_SESSION['cid']=$id;
        $flag="false";
    }
    $result=array("isData"=>1,"cid"=>$_SESSION['cid'],"flag"=>$flag);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Here the above console giving the output as `{ isData: 1, cid: Array[4], cat_id: "17" }`.Here i can store the value and get as well. My second Ajax call is given below.

```
sid=20
var url="common.php?action=setsubcatid";
$.post(url,{"subcat_data":sid},function(data){
    var obj=JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('subdata11',obj);

})
```

Here I am trying to store another id using different key using below php code.

```
if($action=='setsubcatid'){
    $id=$_POST['subcat_data'];
    $cat_id=$_SESSION['cid'];
    session_start();
    if(array_key_exists('subcat_id',$_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION['subcat_id'])) {
        //unset($_SESSION['cid']);
        session_unset('subcat_id');
        $_SESSION['subcat_id']=$id;
        $flag="true";

    }else{
        $_SESSION['subcat_id']=$id;
        $flag="false";
    }
    $result=array("isData"=>1,"subcat_id"=>$_SESSION['subcat_id'],"flag"=>$flag,'cat_id'=>$cat_id);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Here also I am trying to return the previous stored id (`i.e-$_SESSION['cid']`) but in respective console I am getting this `subdata11 Object { isData: 1, subcat_id: "20", flag: "true", cat_id: null }`. Here I could not get the previous stored `$_SESSION['cid']` value. I need until the session has not destroyed I should get all session key value.

Comment: have you tried to work with named session? `session_name('mySession')` before `session_start()`. i remember there was something like this simple to get it work, but i'm not sure at moment because not at work this time.

Comment: @TypedSource : No,i dont use `session_name('mySession')` .Can you share your idea.

Comment: session_unset doesn't unsets by a key, it does unset all session variables, read docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Comment: @Mr_KoKa :How to unset asingle key value.

Comment: @satya to unset a single session key manipulate the session array: `unset($_SESSION['myKeyToRemove']);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  session_name('mySession'); 
  // this helped in my case to set the cookie and use it in js
  session_start();

  ...

  switch($action) {
    case 'todo':
      // do anything;
      break;
    default:
      echo 'you have no rights, the session will be terminated now';
      session_write_close();
      $_SESSION = [];
  }
  // session is not longer available here
```

by the way, it can be very usefull to start (rebuild) the session every time only close (destroy) it if you are sure u have a logout or something like this.

Comment: if a session is destroyed once you can not recover it because the cookie has no legal force longer. what i forgot is to say, have a look on your php config if sessions are realy using cookies (normaly should be the default setting)